# Unable to show the elements in a single line in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

My Android layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Ds6"
                android:textColor="@color/notification_ds6_secondary_text"
                tools:text="Watched item ends in 6 minutes in "
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:ignore="Deprecated"/>

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/notification_countdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="left|bottom"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Ds6"
                android:textColor="@color/notification_ds6_secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="10:02 AM" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/notification_countdown_60s"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/alert_color"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Ds6"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="10:02 AM" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_time_expired"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/notification_ds6_disabled_text"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Ds6"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall"
                android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

[image: TextView and other views]

I want the text view content to wrap correctly to accommodate the Chronometer # 1, Chrometer # 2 and Chronometer # 3 to be displayed on a single line. This does not happen for longer text strings.

But if I reduce the text string length as shown below, and I can see all the elements in a single line. How do I display all the elements in a single line? I want the text to wrap but the two chronometers, and text view # 2 have to be on the same line as the first text view.

This is going to be shown in a notification remote view, so I can't use ConstraintLayout. I can only use FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, and LinearLayout.

[image: Single line elements]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in your `notification_content` `TextView`

Try this way

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:text="Watched item ends in 6 minutes in "
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="Deprecated"/>

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/notification_countdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="left|bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="10:02 AM" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/notification_countdown_60s"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="10:02 AM" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_time_expired"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```